# Characters not showing up correctly when using textInput in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, keyboard

I have a textInput field form that's not displaying the characters it should when typed into. E.g. when the letter "æ" on my keybard is pressed "¾" shows up. This only happens once the flash movie is being displayed in a browser (that is embedded in html), preview through flash does not have this problem. The font is properly embedded as "nameInp.text = "ÆæÖö" shows the correct text in the textInput. It is only when I try to type when it doesn't work as it should.

I have Window mode set to window and I've tried setting "System.useCodePage = true;"

Anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: Just a guess -- you may need to change the HTML encoding to reflect the keyboard layout you want the OS to assign.  I could imagine a browser, e.g. IE, changing the keyboard layout according to web page encoding because of assumptions about what the backend will be expecting from an, e.g., subsequent POST of FORM data.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case fix is to change the font to Verdana and use system fonts to render this input text. What you have done sounds 100% correct.

I would double check.

1. Open the text properties of that input field
2. Click the embed button. Make sure multiple fields in the select box a checked, like basic latin etc.
3. Make sure in that in the text box below it has "ÆæÖö" for other characters.
4. Even though your characters appear on the stage when the swf is not running wont mean they are embed correctly.  If it works when the swf is running in the standalone flash player then I would change how you embed your flash in html. I have never had an issue with SWFObject.

Cheers, John.

Comment: Well I tried disabling the font property of the textInput fields and that has no effect on this matter, still does not display letters properly. Appears to be the same as the wmode bug, yet I have wmode value = window.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you've hit the hideous [wmode bug](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-501). This bug is been there for ages and adobe seems to be unabled to sort it out (which is a shame, if you ask me).

A possible fix is not using wmode (meaning, using the default wmode, which is "window"). This is the sanest option, but might not be possible if you need wmode transparent / opaque for other reasons. Or google for wmode bug fix and you'll find some people that apparently found workarounds using javascript (I never tried any of these myself)

Comment: Like I said in my post I have wmode set to window... so that doesn't seem to be to problem.

Comment: @Bjorninn. My bad, I obviously missed that part.